# Convert BigDecimal Object to double value

Tags: java, casting, double, bigdecimal

I am querying a database with a jdbc connection:

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(SELECT_QUERY);   
    for(Map row : rows) {
        Results result = new Results();
        result.setResultValueDouble((Double)row.get("AMOUNT"));

        //add the data object to the list
        resultList.add(result);
    }
```

However, the object I query is in BigDecimal and I would like to convert it to plain double. Using a cast does not work and gives me a `ClassCastException`.

Any recommendations how to cast this Object properly?

I appreciate your reply!

Comment: Why do you want to convert to double you will lose precision?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
result.setResultValueDouble(((BigDecimal)row.get("AMOUNT")).doubleValue());
```

A cast on an object doesn't change the type of the object, only the type of the expression you use to refer to it, so it can't convert a BigDecimal to a Double, since a BigDecimal *isn't* a Double. Instead, call the [`doubleValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#doubleValue--) method of the BigDecimal.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`BigDecimal.doubleValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#doubleValue--) method.

> `public double doubleValue()`
>
> Converts this BigDecimal to a double. This conversion is similar to the narrowing primitive conversion from double to float as defined in section 5.1.3 of The Java™ Language Specification: if this BigDecimal has too great a magnitude represent as a double, it will be converted to Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY or Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY as appropriate. Note that even when the return value is finite, this conversion can lose information about the precision of the BigDecimal value.

Answer (score 1):

I'll teach you to fish, I guess:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Go to methods, check for which one returns a double, et voila: `doubleValue()`

Answer (score 0):

Use doubleValue() of the BigDecimal.  BigDecimal class has a doubleValue() that will return the equivalent double value.  But I wouldn't reccommend casting to double if precision is important you will lose precision with double vs. BigDecimal.

```
result.setResultValueDouble(row.get("AMOUNT").doubleValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to handle nulls you may need to do something like this:

```
BigDecimal amt = (BigDecimal)row.get("AMOUNT");
result.setResultValueDouble( amt != null ? amt.doubleValue() : 0.0)
```